# Pause in an ASP.NET Chart Series

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

**The problem:** I've got an ASP.NET 4.0 chart object which dynamically generates a series for latency data for a modem in the field. The overall page does a lot more and the chart also displays some other stuff, but it's outside the scope of this. The series is being generated from SQL grabbing the information from a database and what I'd like to see is the the chart literally skip when the remote goes offline. I'm displaying the last hour's worth of data from when the modem was in the network, but let's say the last time it was in the network was under an hour ago and it just went offline, so I want to see its state as it went offline.

**The conditions:** Essentially, what if a modem was in the network, went offline, came back in, went offline, and came back all in under an hour? One would hope that there would be gaps in the chart series. At the moment, the way the SQL query handles this is that it ignores both NULLs and latency values under 300ms because that's technically an impossible value for satellite.

**The question:** If I were to tweak my query to not throw out the 0's, is there a way I could get it to show gaps in my graph? Can the charts support this? Would it instead require multiple series (which would be a bear to implement)? Is there another way I'm not thinking of?

**The caveat:** I can post code if need be, but it's not strictly necessary since this is more of a conceptual / is it possible kind of question.

I've been working on this project for weeks and am nearly done, so I've had to come back to address this issue and so few people have a good grasp on chart controls that I figured this would be the best place to ask since I haven't found anything after tweaking the query and chart settings or searching on Google for a few hours.

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

**Update:** It turns out there is relevant code. I had completely forgotten there were different ways to dynamically generate chart series. It's true that it could be point-by-point. If I were doing it that way, it would certainly be easier. Instead, my series handler looks like this:

```
protected Boolean Chart_A_Line(string query, string seriesName, int queryType, string connnectionString)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connnectionString);
    Boolean chartEmpty = true;

    using (con)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);


        switch (queryType)
        {
            case 0:
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RemoteId", remote);
                break;
            case 1:
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IRID", inrouteId);
                break;
        }

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NMS", nms);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader chartReader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (chartReader.HasRows)
        {
            chartEmpty = false;
            LatencyCNChart.Series[seriesName].Points.DataBindXY(chartReader, "Time", chartReader, "Data");
        }

        con.Close();

        return chartEmpty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure how you're adding data to your chart, but when you add a new point to a data series, you can set its [`IsEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapoint.isempty.aspx) property to `true` ([as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456677.aspx)).

You can also use [`DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datamanipulator.insertemptypoints.aspx).

As long as you know all the `0` values in your data definitely mean a gap value, then you can just make the appropriate call for each `0` value to set a gap in the graph.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that is important. I'll post that cost in a few. If it weren't binding the entire series at once, it would definitely be that easy. Instead, I'm using a data reader and the DataBindXY method.

Comment: @Cthulhu You should be able to Data-bind a data point to values of type DBNull if that would work for you. It mentions that in one of the links I posted.

Comment: I completely missed that link! I'll have to try it after the weekend and see if I can get it to do that. The thing that worries me is the data reader adds all the points at once where this requires each point to be added manually. I'll have to read more about it and test it when it's not time to leave, but thanks for the information! I'll definitely mark your answer as correct if it works Monday. Thanks!

Comment: @Cthulhu I have a feeling that the data binding for DBNull works via [`Binding.NullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.nullvalue.aspx) where you can bind it to a `DataPoint` that has `Empty = true`, but I've not tried that myself.

Comment: @Mathew Awesome! It turns out that your suggestions led me to the solution I needed. The chart itself actually handles skips and pauses in the data so long as the values are actually NULL since any numerical value just gets charted and ignoring numbers leads to slightly inaccurate lines. What I'll end up doing to fix this is to use the SQL query to treat any number under my threshold as NULL and it will cause the breaks and pauses for me. Thanks so much for your help!